# Running macOS pkg installer silently inside other pkg installer

Tags: macos, silent-installer

We are using [Packages-application](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html) to create pkg-installer for our macOS application. Now we need our installer to (silently) install a third party pkg during our application install process.

We are trying to achieve this with post-installation script.

```
sudo installer -pkg "third_party_installer.pkg" -target /
```

Packages documentation explains we can add additional resources to installer that can be accessed by post-install script. I do not understand how exactly can we reference to "third_party_installer.pkg" from post-install script when it is added to additional resources.

[image]

Is this the best approach to solve our issue? Another option could be to copy third party pkg to same folder (Applications) as main application, then run install script and finally delete the pkg-file from post-install script.